# Slice view for C++20 ranges

Tags: c++, stl, slice, c++20

Python's `itertools` has the `islice(seq, start, stop, step)` procedure that takes a sequence and returns an iterator of every `step`th value of the sequence values between `start` and `stop`.

Does the Ranges library of C++20 provide a similar functionality, e.g. a function like `slice` that takes a random access iterator `start`, a sentinel `stop`, and a step value `step`, and that returns a random access iterator that iterates over every `step`th value between `start` and `stop`?

In case it does not, can such an iterator adapter be implemented using the primitives provided by the Ranges library?

(I know how I can implement such an adapter by hand, so this is not the question.)

Comment: range-v3 has `stride_view` and `span` which can be combined to same effect. I don't know if C++20 has all of ranges-v3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite.

C++20 will have [`view::iota`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota) which gives you a sequence from a starting value to a sentinel. However, it does not have the stride functionality. It only increments (via `++`).

However, you can combine it with [range-v3's](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) [`view::stride`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) to add in the steps. That is:

```
auto evens = view::iota(0, 100) | view::stride(2); // [0, 2, 4, 6, ... ]
```

For existing ranges, there's `view::slice`, which also doesn't take a stride. But these are orthogonal and layer nicely:

```
auto even_teens  = view::iota(0, 100)
                 | view::slice(10, 20)
                 | view::stride(2); // [10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Indeed, `view::slice` and `view::stride` will do together what I have been looking for. (Unfortunately, if these are not included in C++ 20, the answer to my original question will be no.) Is there any documentation on range-v3's `view::slice` and `view::stride`?

Comment: @Marc I don't think so. Best bet is to look at the tests and the declarations I think.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunaltely, `slice` and `stride` of [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), as presented in [Barry'sanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56638545/2675154), are not (yet) available in the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) of [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20).
However, you can replace `slice` by combining [`std::views::drop_while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_while_view) and [`std::views::take_while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_while_view). To replace `stride`, you can use the range adaptor [`std::views::filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) and pass a specific [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to it. To filter for every other element as in Barry's example, I would use a stateful lambda expression with an [init capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Lambda_capture_expressions). You can put everything together to represent the range `[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]` as follows:

```
auto even_teens = std::views::iota(0, 100)
                | std::views::drop_while([](int i) { return i < 10; })
                | std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i < 20; })
                | std::views::filter([s = false](auto const&) mutable { return s = !s; });
```

For a more universal stride solution, you can use a counter along with the modulo operator in the lambda expression. To be able to specify the stride size `n` in a readable way, I would use the following lambda expression, which provides another lambda expression that keeps track of the stride operation:

```
auto stride = [](int n) {
    return [s = -1, n](auto const&) mutable { s = (s + 1) % n; return !s; };
};
```

All in all, the final solution looks like this:

```
auto even_teens = std::views::iota(0, 100)
                | std::views::drop_while([](int i) { return i < 10; })
                | std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i < 20; })
                | std::views::filter(stride(2));
```

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IrDDuPMxtZNuSdPw)